# Node.js NPM error when installing PhoneGap on Windows 8

Tags: npm

I don't know if it's just too early in the morning but I can't figure out this error

```
    18075 error Error: ENOENT, lstat 'C:\Users\Philippe\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\plugman\node_modules\npm\html\doc\api\npm-prune.html'
18076 error If you need help, you may report this log at:
18076 error     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
18076 error or email it to:
18076 error     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
18077 error System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
18078 error command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "phonegap"
18079 error cwd C:\Users\Philippe
18080 error node -v v0.10.18
18081 error npm -v 1.3.8
18082 error path C:\Users\Philippe\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\plugman\node_modules\npm\html\doc\api\npm-prune.html
18083 error fstream_path C:\Users\Philippe\node_modules\phonegap\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\plugman\node_modules\npm\html\doc\api\npm-prune.html
18084 error fstream_type File
18085 error fstream_class FileWriter
18086 error code ENOENT
18087 error errno 34
18088 error fstream_stack C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fstream\lib\writer.js:284:26
18088 error fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
18089 verbose exit [ 34, true ]
```

I would be very appreciative if someone could give me the short and sweet version.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ran the following commands

```
npm list -g
```

it showed me that I have an unmet dependency phonegap... so I ran

```
npm rm phonegap
npm cache clear
```

then tried installing it again

```
npm install -g phonegap
```

and it worked, the ENOENT error should have been a dead give away that npm was trying to tell me that the supposed files didn't exist or were corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

@Torvos answer: please note sometimes you must run

```
npm rm -g phonegap
```

(at least for me this was the case; without -g option it didn't work)