# phonegap npm install error

Tags: node.js, cordova

I was installing phone gap.
In phone gap website its shows the commands and instructions.
I installed nodejs and executed the commands.
But resulted in error.

I tried 
[Node.js NPM error when installing PhoneGap on Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18894516/node-js-npm-error-when-installing-phonegap-on-windows-8)

Can u give a step by step instruction ?
I have downloaded phonegap.zip
where do i place this ?

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs>npm install -g phonegap
npm ERR! not found: git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "phonegap"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Program Files\nodejs
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! code ENOGIT
npm ERR! Error: EPERM, open 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm-debug.log'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM, open 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm-debug.log']
npm ERR!   errno: 50,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\npm-debug.log' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "phonegap"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Program Files\nodejs
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.14
npm ERR! path C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno 50
npm ERR! stack Error: EPERM, open 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm-debug.log'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed GIT and it worked!